# What should be the proper word ending of the word "посадка"

Tags: падежи, окончания, дательный-падеж, винительный-падеж, inflection

In a phrase

> посадк**у** на Луну предшествовали трениров<strike>а</strike>**о**чные полеты

The ending **-у** of the word "посадка" does not sound right for me.

What is the proper ending to use in such case?

Comment: You are supposed to make an effort yourself before asking for help. *Предшествовать* requires a dative noun, so (look-up https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/посадка) it's *посадке*.

Comment: @AlexVB Hi. Nothing to do with the question itself, but the interface of the Russian Wiki on your link is quite different from the one that I'm familiar with. How come? :) https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8 Your version is much easier to read.

Comment: @Alone-zee it's a mobile version, the URL is ru.M.wiktionary.org

Comment: Great that you have a feeling that it's wrong. But notice that if the word was masculine, the correct (dative) ending would often be -y: _полет**у** на Луну предшествовали испытания._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrected: "посадк**е** на Луну предшествовали трениров**о**чные полеты".
Dative case used: "*to which* [Moon landing] something [training flights] was something [forerunner]".

Answer (score 1):

Accusative is governed by another verb, synonymous to **предшествовать**, namely **предварять**

> посадк**у** на Луну **предваряли** тренировoчные полеты

Semantically they're not completely identical, but still can be used as substitutes of each other.